# Can't type a single/double quote in Android Studio when using dead keys

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio, keyboard, ubuntu-14.04

This problem appeared just now, before everything worked fine. I did not change any settings since installation of Android Studio, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Whenever I try to type a single quote (<kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) or a double quote (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>), Android Studio to just write the space. Also trying to add two quotes at the same time (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>) doesn't work, then nothing happens at all.

This happens when editing both Java and XML files. In other programs I don't have this problem. Is there some kind of setting I changed with some shortcut?

I'm using the keyboard layout English International with dead keys. When using AltGr dead keys, I can add quotes with <kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>. However, I'd like to have it work with dead keys.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It turned out to be related to [this bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860). There are several solutions in this thread, the one that worked for me:

#### Solution 1

Edit `studio.sh` and add at the top:

```
XMODIFIERS=studio.sh
export XMODIFIERS
```

---

There were other solutions, that did not work for me, but maybe for you:

#### Solution 2

Run `sudo ibus restart`.

#### Solution 3

Run `ibus-daemon -rd`.

#### Solution 4

Disable ibus all together.

Comment: The XMODIFIER solution also works for Intellij IDEA.

Comment: Worked perfectly with Intellij IDEA under Fedora Linux. I created an alias:

alias idea="XMODIFIERS=idea.sh idea.sh"

and after putting the directory where idea.sh is (i.e. $IDEA_HOME/bin) in the PATH, everything works perfectly when launching the IDE with idea. Thanks.

Comment: Could someone indicates where is studio.sh or idea.sh and what's the difference between them? Which one to actually use (studio.sh or idea.sh)? I have pycharm and found no trace of idea.sh nor studio.sh on my ubuntu 16.04 system.

Comment: @calocedrus it depends on whether you use Android Studio (studio.sh) or Intellij Idea (idea.sh). It is in the installation directory, then `bin/idea.sh`. You can also find it with `locate idea.sh`. For pycharm, I would guess `locate pycharm.sh`, or you can do `cat "$(which pycharm)"` which should have the shell script listed somewhere.

Comment: @Keelan excellent. I am not familiar at all with this series of IDE, just installed PyCharm few days ago. It is `pycharm.sh` indeed and it was in `/opt/pycharm-community-2017.x.x/bin/`. Your solution 1 above works fine for PyCharm as well (modifying pycharm.sh).

Comment: I'm on a Mac using IntelliJ installed via JetBrains Toolbox.  Should I also have an idea.sh?  When I "show package contents" of the application I don't see an idea.sh in `IntelliJ/Contents/bin`.

Comment: where is studio.sh?

Comment: @NinjaCoding `find -name studio.sh` in the installation directory says `./bin/studio.sh`.

Comment: i did it typing this in terminal: locate studio.sh, but thanks bro.

Comment: locate is much faster than find -name

Comment: Ok, this worked for me ussing: Ubuntu 18.04.1 + Elementary OS 5.0 Juno.

Comment: Can you please explain why does the `XMODIFIERS` trick work? Does it have any other implications on my OS?

Comment: if you one a one-liner to fix any Jetbrains IDE: `APP=phpstorm.sh; locate -0 $APP|while read -d '' f; do sed -i -e '1aXMODIFIERS='$APP -e '1aexport XMODIFIERS' "$f"; done`. This is useful when you have several versions in parallel or if they are installed through Jetbrains Toolbox.

Comment: Please note you don't need `XMODIFIERS=studio.sh`, you just need to enter empty XMODIFIERS, as in `XMODIFIERS=`

The variant you've used works only because `XMODIFIERS=<anything invalid>` is just ignored by the system.